# Type inference seems like a magic

Tags: haskell

I have following code snippet and could not configure it out, how it works:

```
embedded :: MaybeT (ExceptT String (ReaderT () IO)) Int
embedded = return 1
```

How it is possible to give only a number and get such as type signature back? How does the compiler do that?

Comment: You forget the `return`. `return` is *not* a keyword: it is a function: `return :: Monad m => a -> m a`.

Comment: You are right. The compiler will not infer *this* type signature. It will infer a much more general one. *You* supply a less general signature to tell the compiler "hey, I know what I'm doing, I want this".

Comment: But how to imaging, how does it works?

Comment: How does *what* work?

Comment: There is not much that works. `MaybeT (ExceptT String (ReaderT () IO))` is a monad. SO `MaybeT (ExceptT String (ReaderT () IO)) Int` is a `Monad m => m Int`. So since the function has a `return 1`, it calls the `return` associated with `MaybeT (ExceptT String (ReaderT () IO))`.

Comment: There is no type inference here. You've told the compiler what type `embedded` has; `return` will simply produce a value of that type, based on the definition of `return` *for* that type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The choice of wording is a bit unfortunate. It's not the case that the expression `return 1` *gives back* the type signature `MaybeT (ExceptT String (ReaderT () IO)) Int`.

As *n.m.* writes in the comments, if you don't supply a type, the expression is much more general:

```
Prelude> embedded = return 1
Prelude> :type embedded
embedded :: (Num a, Monad m) => m a
```

By annotating with a type, you explicitly state that you want something less general than that.

Specifically, you state that you want the type `MaybeT (ExceptT String (ReaderT () IO)) Int`.

How does `return` work? `MaybeT m a` is a `Monad` when `m` is a `Monad`, and `return` is defined like this:

```
return = lift . return
```

The right-hand `return` is the `return` function that belongs to the 'inner' `Monad`, whereas `lift` is defined by `MonadTrans` and lifts the underlying monadic value up to `MaybeT`.

That explains how a `MaybeT` value is created, but isn't the whole story.

In this case, the 'inner' `Monad` is `ExceptT String (ReaderT () IO)`, which is another `Monad` (in fact, another `MonadTrans`). `return` is defined like this:

```
return a = ExceptT $ return (Right a)
```

Notice that this is another nested `return`, where the right-hand `return` belongs to yet another nested `Monad`.

In this case, the nested `Monad` is `ReaderT () IO` - another `MonadTrans`. It defines `return` like this:

```
return   = lift . return
```

Yet another nested `return`, where the right-hand `return` is the `return` defined for `IO` (in this particular case).

All of this is parametrised with `a`, which in this case you've constrained to `Int`.

So `return 1` first takes the pure value `1` and packages it in `IO Int`. This then gets lifted to `ReaderT () IO Int`, which again gets packaged into an `ExceptT String (ReaderT () IO) Int`. Finally, this values gets lifted to `MaybeT`.